# Send an e-mail alert after dynamically calculated hours

Tags: apex, tasks, email-alert

When the priority in a task is changed I calculate dynamically the calendar hours.

The calculated calendar hours are set and updated in a custom field called "timeframe".

After the value in the "timeframe" field is changed I want to send an e-mail alert based on the number of hours set in the "timeframe" field.

Example:
If task priority is set to "High", the calendar hours in the "timeframe" filed will be 23 hours.

I want to know how to send an e-mail alert after 23 hours?

Could you please advise how to do that in Salesforce?

Comment: is that my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom date time field and calculate date and time when task priority is set to High.

Let's say, if user currently update the task priority then update the

```
custom date time value = Current Time + 23 hours + 1 hour.
```

Now, Create a time based workflow and send an email **1 hour before** custom date time value. So, ideally, system will send the email after 23 hours.

Hope it makes sense!